# Откуда у svg иконок, добавленных с помощью спрайта, появляются отступы?

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Вот несколько svg иконок, добавленных спрайтом.

```html
<svg display="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="15px" height="15px">
                        <path d="M512,97.248c-19.04,8.352-39.328,13.888-60.48,16.576c21.76-12.992,38.368-33.408,46.176-58.016
                        c-20.288,12.096-42.688,20.64-66.56,25.408C411.872,60.704,384.416,48,354.464,48c-58.112,0-104.896,47.168-104.896,104.992
                        c0,8.32,0.704,16.32,2.432,23.936c-87.264-4.256-164.48-46.08-216.352-109.792c-9.056,15.712-14.368,33.696-14.368,53.056
                        c0,36.352,18.72,68.576,46.624,87.232c-16.864-0.32-33.408-5.216-47.424-12.928c0,0.32,0,0.736,0,1.152
                        c0,51.008,36.384,93.376,84.096,103.136c-8.544,2.336-17.856,3.456-27.52,3.456c-6.72,0-13.504-0.384-19.872-1.792
                        c13.6,41.568,52.192,72.128,98.08,73.12c-35.712,27.936-81.056,44.768-130.144,44.768c-8.608,0-16.864-0.384-25.12-1.44
                        C46.496,446.88,101.6,464,161.024,464c193.152,0,298.752-160,298.752-298.688c0-4.64-0.16-9.12-0.384-13.568
                        C480.224,136.96,497.728,118.496,512,97.248z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="22 0 53.124 96.123" width="9px">
                        <path d="M72.089,0.02L59.624,0C45.62,0,36.57,9.285,36.57,23.656v10.907H24.037c-1.083,0-1.96,0.878-1.96,1.961v15.803
                        c0,1.083,0.878,1.96,1.96,1.96h12.533v39.876c0,1.083,0.877,1.96,1.96,1.96h16.352c1.083,0,1.96-0.878,1.96-1.96V54.287h14.654
                        c1.083,0,1.96-0.877,1.96-1.96l0.006-15.803c0-0.52-0.207-1.018-0.574-1.386c-0.367-0.368-0.867-0.575-1.387-0.575H56.842v-9.246
                        c0-4.444,1.059-6.7,6.848-6.7l8.397-0.003c1.082,0,1.959-0.878,1.959-1.96V1.98C74.046,0.899,73.17,0.022,72.089,0.02z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="in" viewBox="0 0 552.77 552.77" width="15px">
                        <path d="M17.95,528.854h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V196.8c0-9.915-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,178.85,0,186.885,0,196.8v314.103C0,520.816,8.035,528.854,17.95,528.854z"/>
                        <path d="M17.95,123.629h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.036,17.95-17.95V41.866c0-9.914-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,23.916,0,31.952,0,41.866v63.813C0,115.593,8.035,123.629,17.95,123.629z"/>
                        <path d="M525.732,215.282c-10.098-13.292-24.988-24.223-44.676-32.791c-19.688-8.562-41.42-12.846-65.197-12.846
                        c-48.268,0-89.168,18.421-122.699,55.27c-6.672,7.332-11.523,5.729-11.523-4.186V196.8c0-9.915-8.037-17.95-17.951-17.95h-64.192
                        c-9.915,0-17.95,8.035-17.95,17.95v314.103c0,9.914,8.036,17.951,17.95,17.951h71.861c9.915,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V401.666
                        c0-45.508,2.748-76.701,8.244-93.574c5.494-16.873,15.66-30.422,30.488-40.649c14.83-10.227,31.574-15.343,50.24-15.343
                        c14.572,0,27.037,3.58,37.393,10.741c10.355,7.16,17.834,17.19,22.436,30.104c4.604,12.912,6.904,41.354,6.904,85.33v132.627
                        c0,9.914,8.035,17.951,17.949,17.951h71.861c9.914,0,17.949-8.037,17.949-17.951V333.02c0-31.445-1.982-55.607-5.941-72.48
                        S535.836,228.581,525.732,215.282z"/>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="instagram" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="15px">
                    <g>
                        <path d="M352,0H160C71.648,0,0,71.648,0,160v192c0,88.352,71.648,160,160,160h192c88.352,0,160-71.648,160-160V160
                        C512,71.648,440.352,0,352,0z M464,352c0,61.76-50.24,112-112,112H160c-61.76,0-112-50.24-112-112V160C48,98.24,98.24,48,160,48
                        h192c61.76,0,112,50.24,112,112V352z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M256,128c-70.688,0-128,57.312-128,128s57.312,128,128,128s128-57.312,128-128S326.688,128,256,128z M256,336
                        c-44.096,0-80-35.904-80-80c0-44.128,35.904-80,80-80s80,35.872,80,80C336,300.096,300.096,336,256,336z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <circle cx="393.6" cy="118.4" r="17.056"/>
                    </g>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="google" viewBox="0 4 24 16" width="23px">
                    <path d="m21.823 9h-2.187v2.177h-2.177v2.187h2.177v2.177h2.187v-2.177h2.177v-2.187h-2.177z"/><path d="m7.5 19.5c4.328 0 7.203-3.038 7.203-7.326 0-.491-.051-.87-.122-1.248h-7.08v2.578h4.257c-.174 1.095-1.289 3.233-4.257 3.233-2.557 0-4.645-2.118-4.645-4.737s2.087-4.738 4.645-4.738c1.463 0 2.435.624 2.988 1.156l2.036-1.954c-1.311-1.227-2.999-1.964-5.025-1.964-4.144 0-7.5 3.356-7.5 7.5s3.356 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/>
                </symbol>
            </svg>

            <div class="logo_icons">
                <svg class="twitter icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="facebook icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="in icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#in"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="instagram icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="google">
                    <use xlink:href="#google"></use>
                </svg>
```

Почему каждая иконка окружена пространством 300*150?

Comment: считай что размер по-умолчанию, переопредели через стили https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#:~:text=The%20default%20300%C3%97150,the%20default%20size%20for%20SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[В комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195696/valera-kvip) **@Valera Kvip** совершенно верно привел [ссылку](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20300%C3%97150,the%20default%20size%20for%20SVG), где объясняется  причина этого эффекта

> The default 300×150 size also applies to inline  elements within
> HTML documents, but that’s a relatively recent consensus from the
> HTML5 specifications: other browsers will by default expand inline SVG
> to the full size of the viewport—equivalent to width: 100vw; height:
> 100vh; — which is the default size for SVG files that are opened
> directly in their own browser tab.
>
> Размер по умолчанию 300 × 150 также применяется к встроенным элементам
> в документах HTML, но это относительно недавний консенсус со
> спецификациями HTML5: другие браузеры по умолчанию расширяют
> встроенный SVG до полного размера области просмотра, что эквивалентно
> ширине: 100vw; высоте: 100vh; - это размер по умолчанию для файлов
> SVG, которые открываются непосредственно на собственной вкладке
> браузера.

Другими словами, - если не указаны размеры SVG, то при добавлении их инлайн способом в HTML, выводятся  размеры холста SVG `300 × 150px` по умолчанию.

В вашем примере добавлен инлайн спрайт с иконками в **один SVG**, но иконки не видны, так как находятся внутри тегов `<symbol>`
Вызываются иконки внутри **другого SVG** у которого  не указаны размеры

```
 <svg class="twitter icon">
    <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
 </svg>
```

Для решения достаточно просто указать ширину и высоту для каждого SVG, где происходит вызов иконки:

```
 <svg class="twitter icon" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid">
    <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
 </svg>
```

Немного подправил viewBox для каждой иконки, чтобы были одинакового размера и расположены по центру viewport

```html
<svg display="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 48 512 416" >
                        <path d="M512,97.248c-19.04,8.352-39.328,13.888-60.48,16.576c21.76-12.992,38.368-33.408,46.176-58.016
                        c-20.288,12.096-42.688,20.64-66.56,25.408C411.872,60.704,384.416,48,354.464,48c-58.112,0-104.896,47.168-104.896,104.992
                        c0,8.32,0.704,16.32,2.432,23.936c-87.264-4.256-164.48-46.08-216.352-109.792c-9.056,15.712-14.368,33.696-14.368,53.056
                        c0,36.352,18.72,68.576,46.624,87.232c-16.864-0.32-33.408-5.216-47.424-12.928c0,0.32,0,0.736,0,1.152
                        c0,51.008,36.384,93.376,84.096,103.136c-8.544,2.336-17.856,3.456-27.52,3.456c-6.72,0-13.504-0.384-19.872-1.792
                        c13.6,41.568,52.192,72.128,98.08,73.12c-35.712,27.936-81.056,44.768-130.144,44.768c-8.608,0-16.864-0.384-25.12-1.44
                        C46.496,446.88,101.6,464,161.024,464c193.152,0,298.752-160,298.752-298.688c0-4.64-0.16-9.12-0.384-13.568
                        C480.224,136.96,497.728,118.496,512,97.248z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="22 0 53.124 96.123" >
                        <path d="M72.089,0.02L59.624,0C45.62,0,36.57,9.285,36.57,23.656v10.907H24.037c-1.083,0-1.96,0.878-1.96,1.961v15.803
                        c0,1.083,0.878,1.96,1.96,1.96h12.533v39.876c0,1.083,0.877,1.96,1.96,1.96h16.352c1.083,0,1.96-0.878,1.96-1.96V54.287h14.654
                        c1.083,0,1.96-0.877,1.96-1.96l0.006-15.803c0-0.52-0.207-1.018-0.574-1.386c-0.367-0.368-0.867-0.575-1.387-0.575H56.842v-9.246
                        c0-4.444,1.059-6.7,6.848-6.7l8.397-0.003c1.082,0,1.959-0.878,1.959-1.96V1.98C74.046,0.899,73.17,0.022,72.089,0.02z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="in" viewBox="0 23 552.8 504.9" >
                        <path d="M17.95,528.854h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V196.8c0-9.915-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,178.85,0,186.885,0,196.8v314.103C0,520.816,8.035,528.854,17.95,528.854z"/>
                        <path d="M17.95,123.629h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.036,17.95-17.95V41.866c0-9.914-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,23.916,0,31.952,0,41.866v63.813C0,115.593,8.035,123.629,17.95,123.629z"/>
                        <path d="M525.732,215.282c-10.098-13.292-24.988-24.223-44.676-32.791c-19.688-8.562-41.42-12.846-65.197-12.846
                        c-48.268,0-89.168,18.421-122.699,55.27c-6.672,7.332-11.523,5.729-11.523-4.186V196.8c0-9.915-8.037-17.95-17.951-17.95h-64.192
                        c-9.915,0-17.95,8.035-17.95,17.95v314.103c0,9.914,8.036,17.951,17.95,17.951h71.861c9.915,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V401.666
                        c0-45.508,2.748-76.701,8.244-93.574c5.494-16.873,15.66-30.422,30.488-40.649c14.83-10.227,31.574-15.343,50.24-15.343
                        c14.572,0,27.037,3.58,37.393,10.741c10.355,7.16,17.834,17.19,22.436,30.104c4.604,12.912,6.904,41.354,6.904,85.33v132.627
                        c0,9.914,8.035,17.951,17.949,17.951h71.861c9.914,0,17.949-8.037,17.949-17.951V333.02c0-31.445-1.982-55.607-5.941-72.48
                        S535.836,228.581,525.732,215.282z"/>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="instagram" viewBox="0 23 552.8 504.9" >
                    <g>
                        <path d="M352,0H160C71.648,0,0,71.648,0,160v192c0,88.352,71.648,160,160,160h192c88.352,0,160-71.648,160-160V160
                        C512,71.648,440.352,0,352,0z M464,352c0,61.76-50.24,112-112,112H160c-61.76,0-112-50.24-112-112V160C48,98.24,98.24,48,160,48
                        h192c61.76,0,112,50.24,112,112V352z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M256,128c-70.688,0-128,57.312-128,128s57.312,128,128,128s128-57.312,128-128S326.688,128,256,128z M256,336
                        c-44.096,0-80-35.904-80-80c0-44.128,35.904-80,80-80s80,35.872,80,80C336,300.096,300.096,336,256,336z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <circle cx="393.6" cy="118.4" r="17.056"/>
                    </g>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="google" viewBox="0 4.5 24 15">
                    <path d="m21.823 9h-2.187v2.177h-2.177v2.187h2.177v2.177h2.187v-2.177h2.177v-2.187h-2.177z"/><path d="m7.5 19.5c4.328 0 7.203-3.038 7.203-7.326 0-.491-.051-.87-.122-1.248h-7.08v2.578h4.257c-.174 1.095-1.289 3.233-4.257 3.233-2.557 0-4.645-2.118-4.645-4.737s2.087-4.738 4.645-4.738c1.463 0 2.435.624 2.988 1.156l2.036-1.954c-1.311-1.227-2.999-1.964-5.025-1.964-4.144 0-7.5 3.356-7.5 7.5s3.356 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/>
                </symbol>
            </svg>

            <div class="logo_icons">
                <svg class="twitter icon" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid">
                    <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="facebook icon" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid ">
                    <use xlink:href="#facebook"  ></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="in icon" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid ">
                    <use xlink:href="#in" ></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="instagram icon" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid ">
                    <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="google" width="24px" height="24px" style="border:1px solid ">
                    <use xlink:href="#google"></use>
                </svg>
```

Comment: Если вы упоминаете комментарий в ответе, то лучше дать ссылку на сам комментерий: " ... в комментарии [@имя][99] привел ... [99]: ссылка-на-комментарий".